# table showing white space instead of actual content on scrolling horizontally (only in mobile)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

when the page is rendered the first time the table is showing a part of the content then the rest of the width is white space and no content showing, if I use the pagination and go to page 2 then back to page 1, the table is all shown but then if I scroll to the right then back to the left it goes white again

here you can see the white space I'm talking about
[image: here you can see the white space I'm talking about]

and here's what should be there (and as I said I got this when I paginated to page 2 then back to 1)
[image: and here's what should be there (and as I said I got this when I paginated to page 2 then back to 1)]

I'm using Vuejs and BootstrapVue table. I don't know what other info would be useful here.

I don't even know where to start, because when I use chrome devtools to open mobile view, this problem doesn't occur.. I'm really clueless!

-- UPDATE --

here's the live link: https://business-abdal-dev.code95.info/ar/invoices/salary-invoices/details/ec599492-a622-ed11-8131-00224899ee26

and this is the code of the table:

```
            <b-table :items="paginatedData" :fields="fields">
              <template #cell()="data" v-if="invoice.details.status.key == 2">
                <div
                  class="edit-cell cursor-pointer"
                  v-if="data.field.editable"
                  @click="
                    data.item.startEdit = true;
                    inEditField = data.field.key;
                  "
                >
                  <input
                    class="form-control"
                    type="number"
                    min="0"
                    required
                    v-model="tableData[data.index][data.field.key]"
                    v-validate="'required|decimal|min:0'"
                    v-show="data.item.startEdit && inEditField == data.field.key"
                    :name="`${data.field.key}__${data.index}`"
                    :data-vv-as="data.field.label"
                    @blur="
                      setEditedValue(
                        data.item,
                        data.index,
                        data.field.key,
                        $event,
                        data.item.InvoiceDetailsId
                      )
                    "
                    @keydown.enter.prevent="
                      setEditedValue(
                        data.item,
                        data.index,
                        data.field.key,
                        $event,
                        data.item.InvoiceDetailsId,
                        data.field.equation
                      )
                    "
                  />

                  <span v-show="!data.item.startEdit || inEditField !== data.field.key">
                    {{ data.value }}
                  </span>
                  <template v-if="data.field.validate.length">
                    <div v-for="(rule, i) in data.field.validate" :key="i">
                      <span
                        v-if="
                          equationValues(data.item, rule.criteria, data.index)
                        "
                        class="text-danger font-12 bold"
                      >
                        {{ rule.errorMessage }}
                        {{
                          SetValidate(
                            data.index,
                            data.field.key,
                            equationValues(data.item, rule.criteria, data.index)
                          )
                        }}
                      </span>
                      <span v-else>
                        {{
                          SetValidate(
                            data.index,
                            data.field.key,
                            equationValues(data.item, rule.criteria, data.index)
                          )
                        }}
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </template>
                  <span
                    v-if="errors.first(`${data.field.key}__${data.index}`)"
                    class="d-block text-danger font-12"
                  >
                    {{ errors.first(`${data.field.key}__${data.index}`) }}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="has-equation" v-else-if="data.field.equation">
                  {{
                    (tableData[data.index][data.field.key] = equationValues(
                      data.item,
                      data.field.equation,
                      data.index
                    ))
                  }}
                  <div></div>
                </div>

                <div class="default-value" v-else>{{ data.value }}</div>
              </template>
            </b-table>
```

Comment: first, kindly share your code, 
and if this is live, kindly share the link also

Comment: @mehmoodkhan I updated to add the link and the code